# Using between and like together

Tags: mysql, sql, between

I am getting some input from the user using jQuery date-picker in the form of `yy-mm-dd` and my database field is a datetime of the format `yy-mm-dd H:i:s`

I am using the user input in the statement

```
select * from incoming_sms where(in_date BETWEEN like '%2014-09-25%' AND '%2014-09-25%') AND service_id = 6015592000103056
```

but this produces an error near `'%2014-09-25%' AND '%2014-09-25%')`. I cannot modify the user input to include the hour and seconds so as to suit my MySQL query.

How would i modify my statement to use only the date i get from the user to show all the results between the two dates?.

Comment: This is typically done with `DATE(in_date)` to truncate it to only the date portion. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date

Comment: What is the datatype of your date/time field in your database? Is it a `DATETIME` or `TIMESTAMP`, or is it a `varchar()`

Comment: (We assume you meant that your table stores it as `yyyy-mm-dd H:i:s` (MySQL's default), otherwise you're dealing with an old fashioned Y2K bug :)

Comment: @OllieJones OP states *"my database field is a datetime"*

Comment: `between like` is not possible. why not `.. where month(datefield) = 9 and year(datefield) = 2014`?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I don't think this is a duplicate. OP is looking to use the `yy-mm-dd` in the predicate. Something like `WHERE in_date BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(...) AND STR_TO_DATE(...)`

Comment: @Kermit Hence my second comment above - there's a mismatch between the _stated_ format yy-mm-dd and the more natural MySQL format used in the BETWEEN attempt yyyy-mm-dd, and I suspect the latter was intended.